# What order should the 1632verse be read?

Tags: suggested-order, 1632-ring-of-fire

Between the novels, the grantville gazettes, the ring of fires collections, plus how the novels splinter into things happening simultaneously but then carrying on…it’s difficult to impossible for someone just coming in (or in my case, returning) to sort out the reading order. I assume, given there are around 100 grantville gazettes that after a certain point they become the main focus? But I just don’t know and there’s no real way to find out.